# psutil pip installation issue for unix

Tags: python-3.x, unix, pip, psutil

### How to replicate the problem:

- get in unix
- Create a virtual environment: `python3 -m venv venv_dummy`
- Get into virtual environment: `source venv_dummy/bin/activate`
- pip install psutil : `pip install psutil`

### Host Info:

- unix like kernel (Linux Mariner). More info: https://github.com/microsoft/CBL-Mariner
- pip version: 21.3.1
- Python version: 3.7.10

### Error:

````
   ```
  Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/ddummy/venv_dummy/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f428vle2/psutil_c32bd82932444031aaff9983e3255a51/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f428vle2/psutil_c32bd82932444031aaff9983e3255a51/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-z3uzjnld/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ddummy/venv_dummy/include/site/python3.7/psutil
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f428vle2/psutil_c32bd82932444031aaff9983e3255a51/
Complete output (46 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_memleaks.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/tests
running build_ext
building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_COMP -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_COMP -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=580 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/home/ddummy/venv_dummy/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_COMP -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_COMP -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=580 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/home/ddummy/venv_dummy/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_COMP -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_COMP -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-cc1 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=580 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/home/ddummy/venv_dummy/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_linux.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-ld -Wl,-dT,/usr/src/mariner/BUILD/module_info.ld -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/mariner/default-hardened-ld -Wl,-dT,/usr/src/mariner/BUILD/module_info.ld build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_posix.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.o -L/usr/lib -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_linux.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file /usr/src/mariner/BUILD/module_info.ld: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ddummy/venv_dummy/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f428vle2/psutil_c32bd82932444031aaff9983e3255a51/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f428vle2/psutil_c32bd82932444031aaff9983e3255a51/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-z3uzjnld/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ddummy/venv_dummy/include/site/python3.7/psutil Check the logs for full command output.
````

### Research and things done so far:

- Followed instruction in this discussion: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1143
- checked for `python3-devel` which is installed properly in the system

```
> sudo yum search python3 | grep -i dev
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-py : Python development support library
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-py : Python development support library
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-devel : The libraries and header files needed for Python development.
python3-py : Python development support library
python3-rbd : Python 3 libraries for the RADOS block device
python3-rbd : Python 3 libraries for the RADOS block device
python3-rbd : Python 3 libraries for the RADOS block device
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-tools : A collection of development tools included with Python.
python3-pybind11 : Development headers for pybind11
```

- tried to install following without success:

```
> sudo yum install python36-devel.x86_64
No package python36-devel.x86_64 available
```

- Tried to install following without success:

```
> sudo yum install python3.7-dev
No package python3.7-dev available
```

- Tried following:

```
>sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ libgcc platform-python-devel
Package gcc is already installed.
Package libgcc is already installed.
No package gcc-c++ available
No package platform-python-devel available
Error(1011) : No matching packages
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot I figure out the issue. Instead of getting in the virtual env, and do pip install, when I ran following, the installation worked:

```
sudo venv_dummy/bin/pip3 install psutil
```

It has been discussed by `dlitster` in the post https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1143